# HttpRequest Header Response C#

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have a problem using the response of HttpRequest() i get the response but just the html not the headers and the key that i am searching is on the header so this is my code

```
HttpRequest rq = new HttpRequest();
rq.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
rq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36";
rq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
rq.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;
rq.ConnectTimeout = TimeOut;
rq.KeepAlive = true;
var str = rq.Get("url").ToString();
if(str.Contains("404")){
}
```

i hope you can help me

Comment: Don't convert the response into a string, instead use that object to fetch the headers you need.

Comment: Does `HttpRequest` even have a `Get` method? I can't find it on MSDN or the reference source, though I may be looking in the wrong place. Either way, grabbing all of the content + headers as a string, then searching the string for `404` is likely going to be a very slow way to go about doing this. But really, from what I'm (briefly) reading, `HttpRequest` doesn't even seem like the class to do what you're after to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer thanks for your help

```
var req = rq.Get("url");
if(req.StatusCode.ToString().Contains("NotFound") ){

}
```